# Ember.js (v2.4.5) component isn't passing up second action

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-components

I've got a very simple component which has two actions, start and stop. These are fired when clicking buttons. The first action is bubbled up to the route and works as expected, however the second action is fired in the component, but never makes it to the route.

I have just started playing around with Ember, but I assume components can preform more than one action?

There are no errors in the console, the button just doesn't do anything and the console log from the route is never displayed.

**Component actions**

```
actions: {

  start() {
    console.log('component start called');
    this.sendAction('start', this.get('item'));
  },

  stop() {
    console.log('component stop called');
    this.sendAction('stop', this.get('item'));
  }
}
```

**Route actions**

```
actions: {
    start (server) {
        console.log('route start called');
        server.set("settings.amazonTask", 'start');
        server.save();
    },

    stop (server) {
        console.log('route stop called');
        server.set('settings.amazonTask', 'stop');
        server.save();
    }
}
```

**Template**

```
<button type="button"
        class="btn btn-default btn-sm" {{action "start"}}>
    Turn on
</button>


<button type="button"
        class="btn btn-default btn-sm" {{action "stop"}}>
    Turn off
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the actions down to your component:

```
{{my-component start=(action 'start') stop=(action 'stop')}}
```

And then you can call then with `sendAction`.

But I highly recommend to use the new syntax and directly access the actions on the `attrs` object. This is much clearer and makes clear whats happening:

```
this.attrs['start'](this.get('item'))
```

Actually the `action` helper just gets an action from the `actions` object and bounds it to the current context. The result of that can be given down to the component and then be called from there, in the context where you executed the `action` helper.

Note that calling the `action` helper on an already created action will not rebound the action but just pass it though.

Comment: This of course worked, I had set the action for start but forgot the action for stop. I'm a bit confused about the rest of your comment though around what you recommend I actually do. Could you provide either a link to the docs/guides or a further detailed example?

Comment: Maybe checkout the [original blog post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_closure-actions). I recommend to not use `sendAction` because its confusing magic and usually identical to `this.attrs['action']()` whis is a clear function call, that also clearly gives a result.